# force xpath to return a string lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am using `lxml` and I have a scrapped page from Google Scholar. Following is a minimal working example and things I have tried.

```
In [56]: seed = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:machine_learning"

In [60]: page = urllib2.urlopen(seed).read()

In [63]: tree = html.fromstring(page)

In [64]: xpath = '(/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/span/button[2]/@onclick)[1]'

In [65]: tree.xpath(xpath)
#first element returns as list
Out[65]: ["window.location='/citations?view_op\\x3dsearch_authors\\x26hl\\x3den\\x26oe\\x3dASCII\\x26mauthors\\x3dlabel:machine_learning\\x26after_author\\x3dVCoCALPY_v8J\\x26astart\\x3d10'"]         

In [66]: xpath = '(/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/span/button[2]/@onclick)[2]'

#there is no second element
In [67]: tree.xpath(xpath)
Out[67]: []     

In [70]: xpath = '(/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/span/button[2]/@onclick)'

#The list contains only one element
In [71]: tree.xpath(xpath)
Out[71]: ["window.location='/citations?view_op\\x3dsearch_authors\\x26hl\\x3den\\x26oe\\x3dASCII\\x26mauthors\\x3dlabel:machine_learning\\x26after_author\\x3dVCoCALPY_v8J\\x26astart\\x3d10'"]
```

As per documentation [here](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), return values can be smart strings, but I cannot get a string output from xpath function. How can I write the xpath so that I get a string output from xpath

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression `string(/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/span/button[2]/@onclick)`, in that case you get a simple string value.

Comment: Yes. I do get a string. Thanks. Can you also elaborate the problem with the approach I took.

Comment: As far as I understand it, when the XPath expression selects a node-set, then in Python you get a list, an empty one, if the selected node-set is empty, or a list with the selected nodes, if element nodes where selected, or in case of text node or attribute node selection, a list with smart strings. If you know your XPath selects at least a single attribute and you want its value instead of a list with a single value then you can always do `tree.xpath(xpath)[0]`.

Comment: yes I can, but I am writing this as part of loop where not all kinds of xpath return single element. Hence writing `tree.xpath(xpath)[0]` is not an option, but the solution above works just fine.